# Decoding bmp images from stdout using go image library

Tags: image, go, ffmpeg

I am trying to decode a bmp image using the image and golang.org/x/image/bmp libraries. The image is output by ffmpeg into stdout. This is the code to get the frame:

```
cmd := exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-accurate_seek", "-ss", strconv.Itoa(index), "-i",
    filename, "-frames:v", "1", "-hide_banner", "-loglevel", "0", "pipe:.bmp")
var out bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

o := bufio.NewReader(&out)
```

and then I decode it using `img, _, err := image.Decode(o)`
However this gives an error of "image: unknown format". I have already registered the bmp format in the main method, and I have successfully decoded actual BMP files from disk previously, just not from stdout.

I have tried just using bmp.Decode instead of image.Decode but this just gives the error "EOF".

I thought maybe I was not getting the stdout in the correct way, but if I just write it straight to a file:

```
o := bufio.NewReader(&out)

outputfile, err := os.Create("test.bmp")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer outputfile.Close()
io.Copy(outputfile, o)
```

then it works fine and I can open it.

Edit: [code](https://github.com/en3wton/movie-barcode-generator/tree/10bf23c0fe118a8fe267c52879ad824697d91689)

Comment: What do you mean by `open it`? What are you using to open the file?

Comment: @leafbebop I just meant I can open it in an image viewer (photos on windows 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** turns out the issue was `-ss` takes time not frame index.

I tried to reproduce the issue but it seems to work for me. Maybe add `cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr` to see if ffmpeg output gives come clue. Could you also post a fully runnable example?

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "image"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"

    _ "golang.org/x/image/bmp"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command(
        "docker", "run",
        "--rm",
        "mwader/static-ffmpeg",
        "-ss", "5",
        "-f", "lavfi",
        "-i", "testsrc",
        "-frames:v", "1",
        "-f", "image2",
        "-vcodec", "bmp",
        "pipe:1",
    )
    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    img, imgFormat, imgErr := image.Decode(&out)

    log.Printf("img.Bounds(): %#+v\n", img.Bounds())
    log.Printf("imgFormat: %#+v\n", imgFormat)
    log.Printf("imgErr: %#+v\n", imgErr)
}
```

Comment: You're right it actually does work, it's just that I am doing this ~2000 times and for some reason it only gives the error after processing a number of frames (exactly 4.2%). I was using goroutines to run this 8 times at once so the error was appearing almost immediately and I incorrectly assumed it just wasn't working at all. I have no idea why it stops after 4.2% though, and it behaves this way with multiple files of different sizes. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/en3wton/movie-barcode-generator/tree/develop) (develop branch)

Comment: Hey, i added some ffmpeg stderr output and got `Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)` ...and looking at the args i think the problem is that `-ss` is used with frame index instead of time. That would explain 4% if the video is ~25 FPS.

Comment: Yes, I was under the impression it took a frame index rather than a time, maybe I should actually bother reading the documentation next time. Fixed it now, Thanks!

Comment: Yes, i think? I am not very knowledgeable on stackoverflow etiquette, I was unsure whether to mark the answer as accepted when it was the comment that was the solution.

Comment: Yeah not suer either. I added an update to the answer at least. Good luck with the project!

Comment: Thank you!, I appreciate your help.